# How to code every time you type a letter are highlighted if Richtextbox and Textbox2 are the same word you type

Tags: c#

I've created a Typing Test Form that already works:

1. The Richtextbox where a Random word or paragraph will be shown
2. The Textbox2 where you type

But How to code everytime you type a letter if the Richtextbox and Textbox2 are equal (==) the same letter you type will be highlighted to color gray on Richtextbox until you completed a word then the whole paragraph

```
{
    private int numberOfWords = 0;
    private int counter = 300;

    string[] randomWords = new string[] {
    "It was Richter Belmont, the legendary vampire hunter, who succeeded in finally ending the menace of Count Dracula, Lord of the Vampires who had been brought back from the grave by the dark priest Shaft.",
    "Being entirely honest with oneself is a good exercise.",
    "With great power comes great responsibility.",
    "Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.",
    "Coming from your friendly neighborhood Spider-Man!.",
    "The time has once again come for the forces of Good and Evil to engage in their ancient battle. Dracula's castle beckons for you. And no man can say who shall emerge victorious.",};

    public Advance()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static void HighlightPhrase(RichTextBox box, string phrase, Color color)
    {
        int pos = box.SelectionStart;
        string s = box.Text;
        for (int ix = 0; ;)
        {
            int jx = s.IndexOf(phrase, ix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (jx < 0) break;
            box.SelectionStart = jx;
            box.SelectionLength = phrase.Length;
            box.SelectionColor = color;
            ix = jx + 1;
        }
        box.SelectionStart = pos;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = randomWords[new Random().Next(0, randomWords.Length)];
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        timer1.Start();
        textBox2.Focus();
    }

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) && (richTextBox1.Text == textBox2.Text))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = randomWords[new Random().Next(0, randomWords.Length)];
            textBox2.Clear();
            numberOfWords += 1;
            label4.Text = numberOfWords.ToString();
        }
        else if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) && (richTextBox1.Text != textBox2.Text))
        {
            string message = "Fail. Try again";
            MessageBox.Show(message);
            timer1.Stop();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            counter = 300;
            numberOfWords = 0;
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            label4.Text = numberOfWords.ToString();
            richTextBox1.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        if (counter == 0)
            timer1.Stop();
        label1.Text = counter.ToString();
        if (label1.Text == "0")
        {
            string message = "Corrected Paragraph ";
            string title = "Result";
            MessageBox.Show(message + numberOfWords.ToString(), title);
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();
            counter = 240;
            numberOfWords = 0;
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();
            label4.Text = numberOfWords.ToString();
            richTextBox1.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        var TypingTest = new TypingTest();
        TypingTest.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        TypingTest.Show();
    }

    private void Advance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        counter = 300;
        numberOfWords = 0;
        label1.Text = counter.ToString();
        label4.Text = numberOfWords.ToString();
        richTextBox1.Focus();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
            richTextBox1.Text = randomWords[new Random().Next(0, randomWords.Length)];
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }



    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       HighlightPhrase(richTextBox1, "a", Color.Red);
    }


}
```

Comment: Wrong event, KeyDown tells you about virtual keys and you don't want to get in the business of translating them yourself to typing keys.  KeyPress tells you about actual characters, it is fired just before it is added to the box.  Depends on what you want to do when you discover is the wrong character, if you set e.Handled = true then it gets swallowed

Comment: Textbox2_keydown is where you press enter if the Richtextbox and Textbox2 are == then gets new Random word to type